# Custom layout manager

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm planning to build my own custom layout manager.

If there is any other way to build one apart from extending the `View` class, because this is the only approach I know for now and would like to know if there is any other way to do it?

Comment: What's wrong with extending `ViewGroup`? What specifically are you looking to avoid?

Comment: Actually im trying to have a custom layout in which i can control the location of view components (for eg. `TextView`, `Button`) and change there location with finger touch. Something similar to the android home screen. I doing it as a learning exercise. Any more suggestions before i dig into it? I will also look into `ViewGroup` class, I didnt knew about it. Thanks

Comment: Actually it would be nice to have a custom layout as the android layouts really suck.  I am looking to writing my own too as these layouts waste more of my time trying to get them to work right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LinearLayout extends the ViewGroup class
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html

TableLayout extends LinearLayout
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html

I assume the source of both these classes are available at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/.

I would have had a look at the classes above and seen if I can extends LinearLayout or if I should extends ViewGroup.

Comment: Thanks dparnas, Ill look into the code. As i have posted a new comment above about what i want to do, maybe you have any more suggestions?

Comment: There is a [mig4android](https://github.com/saynomoo/mig4android). [MigLayout](www.miglayout.com) is awesome, but there are some bugs in mig4android, hope someone can improve it. That will be a great work for android developers.